# app and app extension fetching contacts from contact book

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, siri, sirikit

Im trying to integrate Siri. For this I turned on AppGrouping for my app. I was trying to use user defaults to save contacts. But it says: "Attempt to set a non-property-list object". What I'm doing wrong?

```
class func allContacts() {
        let store = CNContactStore();

        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactFamilyNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,CNContactImageDataKey as CNKeyDescriptor,CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey as CNKeyDescriptor,CNContactNicknameKey as CNKeyDescriptor])
        var localContacts = [INContact]()

        do{
            try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, status) -> Void in
                let newContact = INContact(name: contact.givenName, phone: contact.phoneNumbers)
                localContacts.append(newContact)
            })
        }
        catch let error as NSError! {
            print ("Error: \(error.domain)")
        }
        guard let shared = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.mygroup.com") else {
            return
        }
        shared.setValue(localContacts, forKey: "Contacts")
        shared.synchronize()
    }
```

How to get list of contacts of app for IntentHandler and fetch it?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? I'm also facing same issue to get all contacts for IntentHandler.

Comment: @cheeseRoot Do you use contacts from local contacts or you have your custom class for contacts?
I saved all my contacts as json dictionary because I have custom class for contacts for my app. Then I write all data to json-file with security application group identifier. And when I call resolveContacts I read this data again to fetch.

Comment: Actually, I think, the problem was with data types, because I was trying to save array of INContact objects to user defaults.

Comment: I have a custom class. I think I also have to write the data to a JSON file, and share it using app groups.